# EclipseLink - JPA - Entitymanager flush() apparently commits data on mysql

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

For what I've read, `EntityManager.flush()` inside a transaction should not commit the data. Especially not, if I'm rolling back my transaction.

Here's a simple chunk of code I'm running for test:

```
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(myEntity);
em.flush();
em.getTransaction().rollback();
em.close();
```

After running this code if I look on MySQL (v.5.x), I see that my entity is persisted, even if I called rollback(). If I remove `em.flush()` the entity is not persisted. But I need to call it in order to have the id updated. So, what's wrong?

Comment: I finally found the solution: InnoDB was not activated. And also when activated, managed tables needed to be converted to use InnoDB engine. Now flush() call does not persist data anymore.